# Safecracker: get constants in javascript

Tags: safecracker, add-on-development, javascript, fieldtype

I'm working on a fieldtype with a lot of javascript and I use the following to get EE constants in the js:

```
$this->EE->javascript->set_global(array('THIRD_PARTY_THEME_URL' => URL_THIRD_THEMES));
```

This works well in the Control Panel, but not in Safecracker, which seems to reset all the EE js object.

Any idea how I can pass those kind of constants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how to answer your specific questions, but I would use my Theme_loader class. It makes life really easy when it comes to loading JS and CSS assets within your module, and it works in Safecracker too. I typically like to extract all these type of components into stand-alone libraries to make code maintenance easier.

Once upon a time, EE didn't have those variables available so when they were released that caused a lot of code to be incompatible (or in need of upgrade). If devs would use an abstraction like this, they would have just only had to update 1 library for all their add-ons.

https://github.com/objectivehtml/Theme-Loader

Comment: Thanks Justin! I finally managed it by injecting my own global object in js. But I will definitely try your library, and try to unify all my addons with it.